# DB2 version of the Query

Tags: oracle, db2

I am new to DB2 and was wonderind how one would write the below query in DB2. It's a fairly basic question I know, I just want to have a comparative view of the two.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR CURRSOR IS 
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPNO=100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN CURRSOR 
       LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NAME OF THE EMPLOYEE IS'|| i.ename);
       END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'THERE IS NO EMPLOYEE WITH EMPLOYEE NUMBER 100');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BEGIN
    FOR each_record AS
    c1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * from EMPLOYEES 
    DO 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('THE NAME OF THE EMPLOYEE IS'|| ENAME);
    END FOR; 
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'THERE IS NO EMPLOYEE WITH EMPLOYEE NUMBER 100');
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks, why you haven't decalre the cursor?  Also each_record is it a keyword? I have read that we can write pl/sql query in DB2 as well. is it true?

Comment: It is not necessary to declare a cursor Explicitly . You can also try out  dynamic scroll cursors, Prepared statements can be executed with the help of it.

Comment: Can I write DB2 codes in PL/SQL also? Please let me know